# Saving CloudWatch's logs in my personal bucket - AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudwatch

Sup guyz,

I would like to save my log files from CloudWatch inside my personal bucket and not in the default amazon's bucket, for easily download then.

Somebody have already done it or just know if its possible?

Comment: Are you referring to [CloudWatch Logs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/CWL_GettingStarted.html) functionality?

Comment: Yes, I wish to save then inside my pesonal bucket, instead of the inaccessible amazon's bucket

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible.

CloudWatch Logs stores its data in [Streams](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/ViewingLogData.html), which are stored within CloudWatch Logs. It is not possible to point CloudWatch Logs to another data store (eg an Amazon S3 bucket).

Logs can be retrieved from CloudWatch Logs via the [`GetLogEvents()`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatchLogs/latest/APIReference/API_GetLogEvents.html) API call.

There is also a [Retention](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/SettingLogRetention.html) setting to determine how long data should be retained within CloudWatch Logs.